# IsolatedStorage on Mono for Android

Tags: webview, xamarin.android, android-videoview, isolatedstorage, isolatedstoragefile

Where exactly is the IsolatedStorage on the android devices. I would have expected it to be in the `/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/[packagename]/` location, but it is not. I used the File Explorer (from eclipse) to try and find it, but I can't.

If I can somehow load a html page into the WebView or play a video from IsolatedStorage, then I won't need this actual path. But, I don't want to copy the movie to a temporary location in order to play it, I might as well just store it on the SD Card.

The reason I am using IsolatedStorage is to minimize the custom code across the platforms, I am developing for the Windows Phone, which only allows for IsolatedStorage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that `IsolatedStorageFile` points towards internal memory only.

I used the `Context.GetFilesDir()` and the `Context.GetExternalFilesDir()` depending on the user's selection.

Answer (score 0):

To determine the directory in which your "isolated storage" aka internal storage is kept, use the **GetFilesDir()** method.  This method is part of the Activity base class.  It is to be used for files you do not want other applications to have access to.

Other useful methods

**GetFilesDir():**
    Gets the absolute path to the filesystem directory where your internal files are saved.

**GetDir():**
    Creates (or opens an existing) directory within your internal storage space.

**DeleteFile():**
    Deletes a file saved on the internal storage.

**FileList():**
    Returns an array of files currently saved by your application.

See the android developers documentation for more [details](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Comment: I suppose what I really want to know is: How do I play movies from IsolatedStorage - the .NET types. I want to use the same/similar code for the obtaining and storing of the data in iso.

Comment: In terms of the android side...I would think that in order to play media you would want to pass that responsibility on to another application through an intent.  With this in mind you are going to want to use external (public) storage so that the receiving application has access to the media location.